# What is the command for Package Manager | Settings | Repositories | Source code

Tags: command-line, apt, banshee

I tried to do step two of [building Banshee from source](http://banshee.fm/download/development/), but it failed as follows:

```
~$ sudo apt-get build-dep banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for banshee
```

I was able to solve this problem by executing *Package Manager | Settings | Repositories | Source code*, followed by the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After which the build-dep step succeeded.

Is there a non-GUI way of enabling the source code repositories for apt-get? The man page says there's apt-get source, but it isn't clear to me that command has the same effect.

Comment: `apt-get source` gets the source code for the program, so that isn't what you want. The answer may be in adding `deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <distro> main universe` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it from terminal by running the following commands:

```bsh
sudo -i   #to switch to the root user
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main universe restricted multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security restricted universe main multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates restricted universe main multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
```

This if you use Ubuntu 13.04. If you use other Ubuntu version, change `raring` with your Ubuntu code name. To see from terminal what is the code name of your current Ubuntu version, use the following command:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Also you can change the mirror server (in this case is the main server http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) with your favorite.